# How to make SFX?

Tags: sound-effects, replication

I wanna know how to make sounds like these:

I wanna know how to make those curly sounds...

Answer (score 3):

I assume that when you say "curly sounds" you're referring to the sounds of 0:30. You can make that sound by starting with a distorted and slightly chorused/phased Square wave. Next make an Envelope with a medium-long attack and decay, with the sustain set at 0. Lets call this Env1.

Set Env1 to control the pitch of the Square, and give it a large range (about 60 semitones). Next create a Sine Wave LFO with a medium-quick frequency. We'll call this LFO1. Let LFO1 also control the pitch of your Square with a small range (around 8 semitones). Also, make Env1 control the rate of LFO1 so the rate speeds up with the attack and slows down with the decay.

This should get you very close to the desired sound, afterwards if you want to add a medium hall reverb and a mild HighPass filter to get closer to the original you may do so.

Here's a Massive Patch I've mocked up that you may use as a reference:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/0m2tigtnna1ovah/CurlySound.nmsv

Comment: How will I open CurlySound.nmsv?

Comment: @JohnMichael you need massive

Comment: @Andyaka what is "massive" ? is it a sound editor?

Comment: It's a VST compatible synth.